# Excel VBA OutOfMemory

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel-File which has round about 3 MB. I now want to delete all rows:

```
Dim maxRows As Double
maxRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Anlagenliste").Rows.Count
Dim a As Long
For a = 26 To maxRows
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Anlagenliste").Rows(a).EntireRow.Delete
Next a
```

when the loop executes the first time, i.e. `a=0` I get a outofmemory exception?
Any ideas?

Comment: maxRows should be a `Long`, never a `Double`

Answer (score 4):

Why loop at all:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Anlagenliste")
  .Range("26:" & .Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim maxRows As Long
maxRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Anlagenliste").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim a As Long
For a = maxRows to 26 STEP -1
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Anlagenliste").Rows(a).EntireRow.Delete
Next a
```

1. maxRows should be `Long`,
2. while deleting like this you should always go backwards (from bottom to top)
3. you should start deleting at the last USED row